# AutoLayout problem when trying to display on iPads or smaller screens

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create an app with this UI.

[image]

I am facing a lot of problems because it's like a rhombus.

I tried to use a vertical stackView and these are my previews and my constrains.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to use aspect ratio(1:1.13 because they are not squares) to resize on all o the screens but on iPad its a lot bigger.
Is there a way to make it smaller on iPads?
I am new to auto layout so I am sorry if this question is not correct.

Comment: Could you add a code or screenshot of constraints you have and a screenshot of UI at problem device?

Comment: So the problem is the amount of space between the two "side" squares? If that's the problem, how big should that space actually be? Or if that's not the problem, what is the problem? Is it that your squares are different sizes on different devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably overthinking this. Instead of a stack view, create a "spacer" view and use constraints to center it and give it the correct height and width for all screen sizes. Test it. Now add the four squares, giving them correct height and width and positioning them in relation to the "spacer" view. Test that. Finally, hide the "spacer" view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your approach and its a lot easier but the problem is with the height. The width for example I want it 35 all the time but the height I want to change dynamically. I used aspect ratio but for the iPad again is too big and for SE is too small.

Comment: Ok so I think I found a pretty good solution. I used "spacer" view and for the height I set it to 20% of the superview so all good. Thank you again.